# Android Xamarin NavigationView handling event error

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin.android, navigationview

I was working  on NavigationView to make easy menu from the following tutorial :
http://maximeesprit.com/en/xamarin-android-actionbar-en/

But i have problem that the following menu items don't send events

My menu looks like this :

[image: NavigationView menu]

And my main.xml code is :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:id="@+id/maintActivity_drawerlayout">
  <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_gravity="start"
      android:id="@+id/maintActivity_navigationView"
      app:menu="@menu/left_menus" />
  <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="240dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
       android:id="@+id/container_layout">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout_viewForFragments" />
  </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

And my mainActivity.cs file :

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Support.V7.App;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Support.V4.Widget;
using Android.Support.Design.Widget;
using Android.Support.V4.View;
// install from NuGet android.support.design
// And App Compat support
namespace App4
{
    [Activity(Label = "TopSideBar App", MainLauncher = true , Icon = "@drawable/ic_launcher")]
    public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
    {
        DrawerLayout m_drawerLayout;
        NavigationView m_navigationView;
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

            SupportActionBar.Title = Resources.GetString(Resource.String.app_name); ;


            m_drawerLayout = FindViewById<DrawerLayout>(Resource.Id.maintActivity_drawerlayout);
            m_navigationView = FindViewById<NavigationView>(Resource.Id.maintActivity_navigationView);
            m_navigationView.NavigationItemSelected += M_navigationView_NavigationItemSelected;
            //Display sandwich menu icon
            SupportActionBar.SetDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            SupportActionBar.SetHomeAsUpIndicator(Resource.Drawable.ic_menu_black_24dp_1x);
            ConfigureNavigationViewHeader();

        }

        private void ConfigureNavigationViewHeader()
        {
            View viewHeader = LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.mainActivity_navigationView_header, null);

            ImageView imageviewUserAvatar = viewHeader.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.mainActivity_navigationView_header_imageview_userAvatar);
            TextView textviewUserPseudo = viewHeader.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.mainActivity_navigationView_header_textview_UserPseudo);
            TextView textviewUserDesc = viewHeader.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.mainActivity_navigationView_header_textview_UserDesc);

            imageviewUserAvatar.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.profile_pic);
            textviewUserPseudo.Text = "Housma Mardini";
            textviewUserDesc.Text = "Web Developer";

            m_navigationView.AddHeaderView(viewHeader);
        }

        private void M_navigationView_NavigationItemSelected(object sender, NavigationView.NavigationItemSelectedEventArgs e)
        {

            switch (e.MenuItem.ItemId)
            {
                case Resource.Id.leftmenu_profile:
                    Toast.MakeText(this, "profile", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                    m_drawerLayout.CloseDrawer(GravityCompat.Start);
                    break;

                case Resource.Id.leftmenu_shopping_list:
                    break;

                case Resource.Id.leftmenu_favorites:
                    break;

                case Resource.Id.leftmenu_params_option:
                    break;

                case Resource.Id.leftmenu_params_about:
                    break;
            }


        }

        public override bool OnCreateOptionsMenu(Android.Views.IMenu menu)
        {
            MenuInflater.Inflate(Resource.Menu.top_menus, menu);
            return base.OnCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        }

        public override bool OnOptionsItemSelected(IMenuItem item)
        {
            switch (item.ItemId)
            {
                case Resource.Id.share:
                    Toast.MakeText(this , "Share" ,ToastLength.Short ).Show();
                    break;

                case Resource.Id.moreoption:
                    Toast.MakeText(this, "Settings", ToastLength.Short).Show();


                break;

                //Handle sandwich menu icon click
                case Android.Resource.Id.Home:
                    //If menu is open, close it. Else, open it.
                    if (m_drawerLayout.IsDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.Start))
                        m_drawerLayout.CloseDrawers();
                    else
                        m_drawerLayout.OpenDrawer(GravityCompat.Start);
                    break;
            }

            return base.OnOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}
```

But when i remove the LinearLayout and FrameLayout tags from my main.xml file every thing is working very well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed by mail, here is the answer :

Your activity axml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:id="@+id/maintActivity_drawerlayout">
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout_viewForFragments" />
  <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_gravity="start"
      android:id="@+id/maintActivity_navigationView"
      app:menu="@menu/left_menus" />    
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```